# Lorentz invariance of Action or Lagrangian?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, action

For what I know, the Action should be Lorentz-invariant in accordance to the axioms of SR. For example for a free particle the Action would be the integral of the proper time, which of course is invariant. Now my doubt is the following: does that mean that the Lagrangian should be Lorentz-invariant as well? In some texts I've read it is often stated that the Lagrangian should be a Lorentz scalar, but how does this assures the Action to be Lorentz-invariant too? For example, once one gets the Lorentz-invariant Lagrangian for the EM field $\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$, why should its action:$$\int -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} d^4x$$ be Lorentz invariant too? Aren't we integrating a scalar over a specific set of  coordinates which *are not* Lorentz-invariant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lorentz invariance of the integration measure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47556/)

Comment: The 4-dimensional volume-element $d^4x$ is invariant on Lorentz-transformations
for a similar reason,
why the 3-dimensional volume-element $d^3x$ is invariant on space rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the specific set of coordinates that we choose is not Lorentz invariant, but when you integrate over *all* space, it doesn't matter. One however has to check that the measure is invariant.

It's a nice excercise to show that, under a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ the integral transforms are
$$
\int \mathrm{d}^4x\, f(x) \mapsto \int \mathrm{d}^4x' \,|\det\Lambda|\, f(\Lambda x')\,.
$$
Since, by definition, Lorentz transformations have determinant $1$ or $-1$, the integral is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

Action is constructed as **Lorentz invariant dencity** integrated over all Minkowski space. $\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ is Lorentz invariant dencity.

**$d^4x$ is Lorentz invariant** measure of integration in rectangular coordinate system.

If you wanna to choose some another coordinate system (curvilinear coordinate system), in general you need consider another measure of integration $d^4y \sqrt{-g}$, $g_{\mu\nu}$ is Minkowski metric in specific coordinates, that one can choose.

$$
g_{\mu\nu}(y) = \eta_{\rho\sigma}\frac{\partial x^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\sigma}}{\partial y^{\nu}}
$$